# Excel VBA Looping Fill for certain cell values

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm doing an assignment in VBA. I recorded a macro that found cells with the search criteria 'central', then I colored it blue-green and got the following Macro:

```
Sub Color()
' Color Macro
' Color a region
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m
'
    Cells.Find(What:="central", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 6723891
     .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
     End With
End sub
```

There are 23 occurances of the word 'central' so I thought I could add  `for k=1 to 23` above the line that starts with `cells.find(what...)`, then add `Next K` above `end with` but when I try I get the error

> next without for

Comment: Did you `Dim k`?

Comment: You can't close the `For` loop before closing the `End With`. You have to close them in "blocks".  Put the `Next k` after the `End With`

Answer (score 2):

Bruce Wayne already told you why you got that error

but if you want your macro to find and process all occurrences of "central" in your currently active sheet no matter how many of them, then you can wrap `Find()` method inside a loop that goes on until all wanted occurrences are found, like follows (explanation in comments):

```
Dim f As Range
Dim firstAddress As String
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange 'reference currently active sheet used range
    Set f = .Find(What:="central", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                  LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                  MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'search referenced range for first occurrence of "central"
    If Not f Is Nothing Then ' if found...
        firstAddress = f.Address ' store first occurrence cell
        Do
            With f.Interior 'reference found cell "Interior" property
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 6723891
                 .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
            Set f = .FindNext(f) ' search for the next "central" occurrence
        Loop While f.Address <> firstAddress ' loop till you wrap back to initial occurrence
    End If
End With
```